# Can I use CodeRush Xpress in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress

I've installed the Beta 1 of Visual Studio 2010, and started working a little. Even though I haven't been using CodeRush Xpress for long in Visual Studio 2008, I immediately started missing some of the neat functionality.

Is there any way to install CodeRush Xpress on Visual Studio 2010, even though it's only the Beta yet?

Comment: I have been searching around for a while, but I'm flooded in hits on the VS2008 version, which won't do me much good. I still have VS2008 installed, with CRX, so I'm a little worried that installing the same add-on on VS2010 will cause conflicts if I can't find a different version (if it'll even work at all...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've listened to a couple of recent Mark Miller interviews and they are still working on the 2010 version. The current version will only work with 2005/8.

Comment: OK. It doesn't solve my problem, but it's the answer to my question. Do you know when the VS2010 version will publish? Thanks!

Comment: Acording to their web site, they are targeting November http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q212966.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Now available at

[Visual_Studio_Add-in_CodeRushX](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/)

Answer (score 1):

We are past November & still no VS2010 version, gosh, y did I get addicted to this thing