# Experience with Coderush XPress and Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress

It is possible to use CRX with VS 2010: 
[Can I use CodeRush Xpress in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441554/can-i-use-coderush-xpress-in-visual-studio-2010)

Refactor Key works. (After assigning the shortcut)

What doesn't work is `QuickNav` and `QuickFileNav`. 
The Standard Shourtcut for QuickFileNav is CTRL+ALT+F, which is conflicted with VS View.F#Interactive.

But removing this shortcut or changing the shortcuts for `QuickNav` and `QuickFileNav` doesn't bring up the nav-windows.

`NextReference` (TABULATOR) doesn't work

Any solutions?

Other issues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, but the following features are no longer included in CodeRush Xpress for VS 2010.  This was a Microsoft requirement, and we (DevExpress) can't violate it.

- Tab to Next Reference
- Highlight References
- Quick Nav
- Quick File Nav
- Declare Method
- Declare Constructor
- Declare Property (auto-implemented)
- Declare Class
- Declare Enum
- Declare Enum Element
- Declare Interface
- Declare Struct
- Declare Field

It looks as if the only thing we can suggest is to install the full CodeRush Pro version if you wish to use these features, sorry.

Comment: That's certainly a shame, but can I suggest making this much clearer on the DevExpress website? I had to find this out by searching and finding this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kent. We'll make it clearer on the DevExpress website.

Comment: Here’s a table of features of CodeRush Xpress for different versions of Visual Studio - http://bit.ly/jeYEms

Comment: @Alex It seems like the flow of your site(and also links from MS as well as googling) most often took me to either of these two sites.  Maybe update these two pages with a bold "For VS 2010" link to the top of these.
http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx
http://tv.devexpress.com/#CRX91FeaturesCS

Comment: @AaronLS I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Would you please clarify what's wrong and where?

Comment: @Alex Imagine I'm a new user.  I try to find out how to use coderush, those were the two pages I found most often either from links on Microsoft's page linking to your site, or googling.  Problem: they demonstrate alot of features that don't actually work because they have been removed in 2010, and it is very confusing.  I thought I was doing something wrong or thought maybe it was buggy.  So I suggest adding a link on those pages with a note in bold indicating that many features are not available in the Express edition because MS provides them in VS2010, and link to the bit.ly/jeYEms page

Comment: @AaronLS Thank you very much for the clarification! I now see what you mean. We are going to make major changes in the CodeRush Xpress version and will take into account your suggestion if appropriate.

Comment: @AlexSkorkin: I wrote a Visual Studio extension for finding files in a Solution that provides very similar features to CodeRush Xpress, I'd be interested in knowing whether you'd share some ideas about implementation as I've been unable to get symbol searching working with any sort of decent performance...

Comment: @AlexSkorkin so much for making this more clear on the website. I just wasted hours downloading DX Core and Code Rush Xpress only to find they don't do anything in VS 2010.

Comment: @Max There are still many features working in Visual Studio 2010. Take a look at this comparison table - http://skorkin.com/2010/07/coderush-xpress-features-differences-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/

Answer (score 10):

VS 2010 *replacements* for CodeRush XPress features that don't work

**Tab to Next Reference**

`Ctrl + Shift + UP/Down` Next reference in current file!

`Shift + F12` Find references in all files

**Highlight References**

done by VS per default

**Quick Nav**

`Alt + F12` for Find Symbol

**Quick File Nav**

`Ctrl + ,` Navigate To feature of VS (no filter for the Type of search: Classes, Files, Members...)

`Ctrl + #` type `>open` then you get auto completion for files

**Declare things** is done by VS

write sth. VS doesn't know, `Ctrl + .` create new type

---

I ended up using **DPack** for **navigation** (ALT+S, ALT+U...)

Comment: DPack rocks! It recommend it everywhere I go! One of the best free add-ons for VS!

Answer (score 2):

I've written an extension that provides similar functionality to QuickFileNav.
Freely downloadable : [**VSFileNav**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdf85c2-aaa4-4bdd-b8ea-e22bcc9860af?SRC=Home)