# Coderush express seems doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush

I installed Coderush express and I can see that it is installed. (I can see that Camel Case Navigation works). But I can see any other feature works. Based on this page: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx

I cannot see any of these feature to works:

1. Tab to Next Reference : no effect when I put caret on a variable and press tab ( a tab inserted at the middle of my variable name!)
2. Highlight All References: pressing ctrl+alt +u add a ascii character to source code.
3. Quick Navigation: Ctrl +Shift + Q has no effect.
4. Quick File Navigation : Ctrl +Alt +F brings up F# interactive
5. Selection Increase and Selection Reduce doesn't work: generate a beep
6. Declare: ctrl +` has no effect.

   and ...

Any idea why this is happening? I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably due to your using a different version of Visual Studio.

The [page you linked to](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx) is pretty clear about it being for Visual Studio 2008, but you've included the visual-studio-2010 tag.

> CodeRush Xpress fully supports all language features of Visual Basic and C# in Visual Studio 2008.

---

**Edit**

Version of Visual Studio wasn't the problem after all.

It appears to just be that the tool makes very little visible change to the Visual Studio user interface, so it looks like it hasn't loaded.

Comment: I installed it from this address: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9741bffc-033d-4c8c-86d7-08060ba98444 which is for VS2010, but I found that page as reference on what is in CodeRush Express.

Comment: Ah right. What edition of Visual Studio do you have installed, then?

Comment: Odd. I'm just having a go at installing it into Visual Studio 2010 Pro - will let you know what happens.

Comment: When you start up Visual Studio now, do you get a load of messages at the bottom-left of the screen saying beginning "Loading DXCore:..."?

Comment: Also, when you do `Tools -> Extensions Manager`, is DevExpress Tools listed?

Comment: Yes. Also pressing alt+shift+ctrl+o bring the coderush config page up. So for sure it is installed. Do you get any menu in your VS? I am not getting any such menu. and yes it is installed (Tools -> Extension Manager)

Comment: No, I can't see any menu - which really confused me, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-arrow</kbd> does do camel-case navigations, and brings up a little **What happened?** popup, with a link to "Options" that has lots of choices. Maybe it's just a minimalist interface!

Comment: This video seems to be quite a good intro, if you're a C# developer - http://tv.devexpress.com/#CRX91FeaturesCS

Comment: I've edited my answer, as a result of this discussion... Do you think your installation is OK now, then?

Comment: The instalation seesm to be ok but some features doesn't work. Do you have all features that listed in the question link with your instalation?

Comment: Well, I tried repeatedly to get Ctrl+` (back-quote) working, on some trivial C# code, and it didn't seem to respond. I do see that there's a huge number of options in the preferences, so maybe some things are disabled... It sounds like it's installed OK for you, so my suggestion would be to watch some videos, or maybe look in [their forum](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/115.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your installation is corrupt. I would recommend you contact [DevExpress Support](http://devexpress.com/sc) directly. The support team is better equipped to resolve any issues you face with their products. They offer a very short response time and high qualification. I would also recommend that you reinstall the product.

Answer (score 0):

The features you are asking about, were removed on purpose from VS2010 version of Coderush XPress. More info here:

[Experience with Coderush XPress and Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719782/experience-with-coderush-xpress-and-visual-studio-2010)